# Using only one property to show/hide a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I have two "grid" and two "radio button". When the "radio button 1" is checked the "grid 1" will be displayed and the "grid 2" hidden. The same happens when the user checks the "radio button 2", the "grid 1" is hidden and the "grid 2" is displayed. How can I use just one property to show or hide a grid view?

I managed to implement this as follows, but it is quite long for such a simple task:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ExibirBandeja" />
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ExibirPainel" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Radio button

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="True" Command="{Binding RadioButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="Painel" Content="Painel" />

<RadioButton Command="{Binding RadioButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="Bandeja" Content="Bandeja" />
```

Properties

```
private bool _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel;
public bool DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel
{
    get { return _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel)
            _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel");
    }
}

private bool _devoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja;
public bool DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja
{
    get { return _devoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _devoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja)
            _devoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja");
    }
}
```

Management method that alternating display of grids

```
private void RadioButton(object tipoDaPeca)        
{
    if (tipoDaPeca.ToString() == EnumHelper.ObterDescricao(TipoDePeca.Bandeja))
    {
        DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = false;
        DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja = true;
    }
    else
    {
        DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja = false;
        DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = true;
    }
}
```

Grids

```
<!-- GRID 1 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel, Converter={StaticResource ExibirPainel}}" ></Grid>

<!-- GRID 2 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja, Converter={StaticResource ExibirBandeja}}" ></Grid>
```

Comment: If you `Grid1` is covering your entire `Grid2` or vice versa, you could just use one property to set `visibility` of the Grid on top (so when it is showing the other grid will be hide automatically).

Comment: It makes sense what you said. I'll try to implement that way. What if my Grid1 were not overlapping the Grid2?

Comment: Then you could use one property for `Grid1` and use another property which will simply return `!proerty1`.

Comment: Did not quite understand. Could you give me example ulgum? Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> Give a name to Radio button and same groupname and bind Grid Visibility to IsChecked of Radiobutton with ElementName as name of RadioButton

```
     <RadioButton IsChecked="True" x:Name="Radio1" GroupName="grp1" Content="Painel" />

    <RadioButton x:Name="Radio2"  GroupName="grp1" Content="Bandeja" />

    <!-- GRID 1 -->
    <Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding Ischecked,ElementName=Radio1, Converter={StaticResource ExibirPainel}}" ></Grid>

    <!-- GRID 2 -->
    <Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding Ischecked,ElementName=Radio2, Converter={StaticResource ExibirBandeja}}" ></Grid>
```

[ElementName Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

You could make a BooleanToVisibilityConverter which has the output visibility as a property:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Visibility VisibilityIfTrue
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public Visibility VisibilityIfFalse
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public void Convert(object value...)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
        {
            return ValueIfTrue;
        }
        else
        {
            return ValueIfFalse;
        }
    }
}
```

And bind to the same property using to different converters:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibleIfTrueConverter" VisibilityIfTrue="Visible" VisibilityIfFalse="Collapsed"/>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="CollapsedIfTrueConverter" VisibilityIfTrue="Collapsed" VisibilityIfFalse="Visible"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- GRID 1 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding TrueFalseProperty, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}" ></Grid>

<!-- GRID 2 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding TrueFalseProperty, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedIfTrueConverter}}" ></Grid>
```

You can also accomplish it entirely without a code-behind property if you bind directly to the radiobuttons:

```
<!-- GRID 1 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=radioBtn1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}" ></Grid>

<!-- GRID 2 -->
<Grid Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=radioBtn2, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedIfTrueConverter}}" ></Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Grid1` is covering your entire `Grid2` or vice versa, you could just use one property to set `visibility` of the Grid on top (so when it is showing the other grid will be hide automatically).
If not then you could at least use one property for `Grid1` and use another property which will simply return !proerty1.:

Properties:

```
        private bool _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel;
        public bool DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel
        {
            get { return _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel)
                    _devoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel");
                RaisePropertyChanged("DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja");
            }
        }


        public bool DevoExibirOpcoesParaBandeja
        {
            get { return !DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel; }                
        }
```

Management method:

```
        private void RadioButton(object tipoDaPeca)
        {
            if (tipoDaPeca.ToString() == EnumHelper.ObterDescricao(TipoDePeca.Bandeja))
            {
                DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = false;              
            }
            else
            {
                DevoExibirOpcoesParaPainel = true;
            }
        }
```

Also: I think you could just use the same `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` for both.

**I do suggest you to have a look of the other [pure XAML solution posted by @ethicallogics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427961/352101), which maybe a better way of doing it.**